# Is it safe to stop consuming sugars?

Tags: nutrition, diet, sugar

I've heard that consuming sugars can induce many different health problems. I wouldn't really mind excluding them from my diet, but would it be safe? Or do we have a minimum sugar requirement?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and borders on personal medical advice. If you could narrow it down to something less broad (for instance, the effects of removing refined sugar from a balanced diet for an otherwise-healthy person) we might be able to answer this.

Comment: @Shog9 Is it really necessary to be overly specific? I thought the otherwise-healthy person and details like that were implied if not specified. Which explicit specifications are being enforced? If you have specific explicit detail requirements for diet (or other) questions, you should make it official, public, and easily available. Otherwise you are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @JCPedroza What kind of sugar? There are [different types](http://www.sugar.org/all-about-sugar/types-of-sugar/), white/brown, natural sugars (from fruits), etc. Basically it's not possible to stop consuming sugar, as you've them in every fruit and vegetables. However I've heard some story that one family stopped eating (white) sugar and they've got great results.

Comment: @kenorb Sugars in general.

Comment: @JCPedroza you don't seem to understand. We are saying your question is *too broad*. Narrow it down and we can help you. In reply to the `Is it really necessary to be overly specific` the answer is yes. Edit to make this better following the commented suggestions and maybe this will be reopened.

Comment: This should be duplicate of: [Which are the effects of removing sugars from a balanced diet for an otherwise healthy person?](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/241/114) anyway, which is better phrased.

Comment: @kenorb I asked that one too, after this one was closed. That one is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: It's both a duplicate and way too broad.

Comment: @JCPedroza if it has been closed you edit to improve in the way we have suggested, you don't re ask a dupe.